# Is there a way to find the most strong regular expression

Tags: regex, boost

I would like to know whether there exists an approach to find the best matching regex from a given list of matching regular expressions.

Suppose following regular expressions are given.

```
"apple.*" 
"ap.*" 
"app.*"
```

And when we searching a match for the string `"apples"` out of above expressions. The correct answer should be. `"apple.*"`. Here all three regular expressions are valid when we evaluating the word "apple" against them. But the most strongly matching regular expression is `"apple.*"` as both strings are almost identical.

It would be great if someone can suggest an approach for this. I am looking to implement this in c++

Comment: The tag for c++ seems odd.  I don't see any "code to be compiled by the c++ compiler" as the tag states.  I'm quite a bit newer than you, so am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @airhuff Read the tag usage for regex: _“Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.”_

Comment: Appreciate the clarification @Xufox,  that makes sense.

Comment: @Xufox: In the case of C++, that rule should probably be extended a bit: the C++ library supports 6 different regex syntaxes: basic, extended, awk, grep, egrep, and ECMAScript. You probably want to choose one.

Comment: Presumably you want to use the regex stuff from Boost, as opposed to the new library functions of C++11?

Comment: @Bathsheba I am looking forward to build a boost + c++ solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the obvious approach would be to start by checking which regexes match against the chosen string. Obviously, any that don't match are eliminated at that point.

Then take those that do match and count the number of literal (non-wildcard) characters they contain. The one with the largest number of literals wins. This could (would) get tricky in cases like: `(short|muchmuchlonger)`

Assuming this matches against a target, it's not immediately clear whether `short` or the `muchmuchlonger` was used in the match, and that difference might well decide whether this pattern was the "strongest" match.

In case of a tie, you could (for example) look at sets like `[abcd]`. In this case, you'd probably rate a *smaller* set like `[abc]` as a stronger match than a larger set like `[A-Z]`. As the latter makes clear, however, the code to count set size would need to know about regex syntax (otherwise, both of those look like three characters).

In the end, what you're looking for is the degree to which a character in the pattern *rejects* characters. Something like `.*` doesn't reject anything, so it adds little (or nothing) to the strength of the regex. A simple literal like `a` or `9` rejects all but one possibility, so it adds a great deal of strength. For a set, the number of characters rejected is inversely related to the number of characters accepted.

Then we get things like `[:alpha:]` or `[:alnum:]`. Again, these are basically just sets, so you'd have to evaluate them in terms of the number of characters they accept/reject.

To do all this, you'd probably want to mark each "piece" of the regex as a sub-expression, so you'd get `sub_match` objects telling you how much each actually matched against. Then you'd multiply each by the percentage of characters that part of the regex would reject to get a strength for each. Put those all together and you get an overall "strength" score.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I also thought of a similar approach. I agree with the fact of checking with regexes match against the chosen string and mismatches are ignoring from that point onwards. What I am thinking is after that point checking the edit distance of candidate regular expressions. One with smallest edit distance will be chosen as the most strong regular expression